# Java and SQLite optimization

Tags: java, sqlite, optimization, jdbc

I have a Java servlet (running in Tomcat) that extracts data from a SQLite database. I'm using the Xerial driver to access the SQLite database from my servlet.

This servlet extracts data when mobile Apps are requesting information.

This database is used only as read-only (it's generated once per day) but it contains huge data (the main table contains 200 000 rows and I have another one with more than 10 000 000 rows). I have created indexes for the columns that are used frequently.

I need advices to optimize the usage of the SQLite database in order to increases the responsiveness of my server.

1. For each request I create a new database connection, then sending the SQL select, extract the data and closing the connection. Is it a good strategy? I can have many requests running in parallel. Should I use a pool of connection? how?
2. My SQLite database file is around 2Gb, on my server I have lot of memory (16Gb). As it's a read-only database I could load it in memory or increase the cache. What is the best strategy and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I as there will be lot of parallel request, opening a connection, performing the operation and then closing the connection for every request will cause performance bottleneck. IO operations are very time consuming. I think you should use Connection Pool. Details are there in java documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/manage.htm

As it's a read only file you can use multithreading without synchronization overhead to improve the performance.

Talking about cache, there are techniques to ensure the frequently used data will reside in the cache. I am not sure if you can have 2GB of cache. Load the file in memory and increase Data locality. You can google the 'Cache Blocking' and 'Loop tiling' techniques which are used to increase the data locality.

Answer (score 0):

Use of pool of connection is better, as you can have many requests parallel.